# How to build android cts with right version?

Tags: android, cts

My target is build CTS for device using android 4.0.3 with some patches.

I prepare the environment like below.

1. android source code 4.0.3R1 with command repo init + repo sync (branch 4.0.3r1.1)
2. I check in android source code and see there is one cts directory here. I use git branch android-cts-4.0.3_r3 to switch to that branch
3. Then make cts

Result I receive after that is CTS 4.0_r1

I tried again with new step 2: create cts source code by delete cts directory in android source code. Then git clone cts source code with tag android-cts-4.0.3_r3

When I build it, I receive these failures.

```
bison -d -o out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aidl_intermediates/aidl_language_y.cpp frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_y.y
Lex: aidl <= frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l
frameworks/base/tools/aidl/aidl_language_l.l:54: warning, rule cannot be matched
logtags: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/services_intermediates/src/com/android/server/am/EventLogTags.java <= frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/EventLogTags.logtags
make: *** No rule to make target `com.replica.replicaisland', needed by `out/host/linux-x86/cts/all_cts_files_stamp'. Stop.
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
build/tools/signapk/SignApk.java:19: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
Note: build/tools/signapk/SignApk.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
22 warnings
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

So my question is how to get right cts version 4.0.3_R3?